# Office.js and @microsoft/mgt dont work together

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I generated a project with `yo office` to create an office add-in based on Angular. When I add the @microsoft/mgt libs to that project (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-angular) I get an error saying

```
SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
```

This happens when I add

```
  Providers.globalProvider = new MsalProvider({
    clientId: environment.clientID
  });
```

to the ngOnInit() of the app.component.ts. Removing this statement loads Office just fine and lets me use my Addin.
Is there anything I can do in my code to fix this? Or is this an imcompatibility between the two Microsoft libraries?

Comment: In my scenario, i initialized the provider in my code, so i provided the permission scopes in an array in the scopes property. Adding the Javascript sample:

import {Providers, MsalProvider } from "@microsoft/mgt";
Providers.globalProvider = new MsalProvider({
  clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
  scopes:['user.read','people.read']
});

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: The example I added was a shorter version of what i actually used. I added scopes to the provider the same way you suggested but that doesn't make a difference. Does your setup work correctly with office.js and the @microsoft/mgt libs?

Comment: I'm still stumped about this issue. Anybody have a clue how to solve it?